# Is the image of a morphism between affine schemes always constructible?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Is there example for $f\colon A\to B$ being ring map, but the image $f^*\colon \operatorname{Spec}(B)\to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$ not constructible? (i.e., written as a finite union of locally closed subsets)

(Since Chevalley's theorem asserts it is true for $B$ finitely presented over $A$, an counterexample must be in the case $B$ is not finitely presented over $A$.)

Comment: $A=\mathbb Z$, $B=\mathbb Q$.

Comment: More generally, any scheme with a non locally closed point will work.